# How to control video and audio live steaming when internet is slow ?(Red5pro app)

Tags: android, red5pro

I am using red5pro android app for live streaming but it stuck on 4G or very high speed wifi( data not received live at receiver end) so i want to know is their any way regarding this issue , i mean any coedec or other method to fix this .